# Melhorar o código para pegar apenas o valor do localstorage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data:  $(accent_color).serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); } });
```

Como faço para este código pegar o valor abaixo:

```
var accent_color = localStorage.getItem("accent_color");
```

E no lugar de `console.log` enviar para um post em php?

O problema é que a variável `data` está pegando o HTML inteiro, não só o valor do localstorage, veja a foto:

[image: alert(data) mostra todo o código html, quero apenas o conteúdo de localstorage]

Tanto que se eu colocar isso:

```
if($_COOKIE["data"]) { echo $_COOKIE["data"]; }
```

Não aparece nada.

Comment: *"e no lugar de console.log enviar para um post em php"* - não percebo o que queres dizer. O Ajax já envia POST para o PHP, mas não deste nenhum endereço de url. O que tem a variável `accent_color`?

Comment: na variável accen_tcolor vem um localstorage, como faço para por a variável localstorage de accent_color dentro de uma variável no lugar do console.log e pegar no post do php normalmente

Comment: `localStorage` é usado para sessão do navegador, o que tem a ver com sua requisição ajax? `localStorage.setItem('chave', valor);` `localStorage.getItem('chave');`

Comment: pra que uma requisição ajax, não entendi?

Comment: basta fazer isso: `localStorage.setItem('accent_color', $('#accent_color').serialize());` e depois: na outra pagina: `var serie = localStorage.getItem('accent_color');`

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu preciso passar o conteúdo de localstorage para uma variável em php, em uma localstorage accent_color tem um valor definido pelo usuário que pode ser o mesmo em outro navegador porém este valor é de cada navegador, com este valor em localstorage eu quero passar para o php, no caso, vi como fazer em ajax mas a idéia de ter mais um arquivo não me animou, eu preciso só que o localstorage entre em uma variavel javascript e passe para uma variável php, como javascript roda no navegador e php no servidor, vi que ajax é a solução, mas, como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um `input` do tipo `hidden` e receber o dado do formulário como POST.

```
<input type="hidden" value="valor" name="accent_color" id="accent_color">
```

Depois basta criar um script pra fazer o input capturar o valor.

```
var accent_color = localStorage.getItem("accent_color");
$('input #accent_color').attr('value',accent_color);
```

Comment: sim, mas, no lugar de console.log eu ponho o que para pergar com php depois? ou só pegar de "dados"?

Comment: @flourigh O `console.log(data)` é apenas uma forma de trazer os dados que foram processados na sua página php,  de volta  para o Ajax. Em termos simplórios , tudo que você escrever lá no php vai voltar para o seu ajax nessa variável data. Mas ao invés de console você poderia retornar um `alert(data)` ou carregar em uma div `$('div .cores').html(data)` ai vai da sua necessidade.

Comment: mas então o erro da página vir toda no alert(vide imagem) ou no console está no ajax? e como não acontecer isso, fazer ele pegar apenas o valor do localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

Veja aqui um resumo de como "capturar" dados de javascript e mandar para php e como recuperar esses dados em php

```
    Recupere os dados em PHP oriundos do Javascript
    $arrayPost = $_POST; //Se foi serializado ou não
    $arrayPost = json_decode($_POST["meuJSON"], true); //Se foi enviado JSON

    //Codigo php que vai processar os dados e mandar de volta para o JS
    $arrToJSON = array(
    "dataPHPtoJs"=>"yourData",
    "asYouWant"=>"<div class=\".class1\">soemting</div>"    
    );  
    return json_encode(array($arrToJSON));




//Javascript que vai mandar algo para o php
$(document).on("event", "#idElement", function(){
     //Vc pode usar 
     var dt={ 
              ObjEvn:"btn_Login",
              dataJsToPHP: $("#txt_EmailLogin").val(),

            };

    //Ajax      
     var request =$.ajax({//http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
                            url: "yourServer.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: dt,
                            dataType: "json"
                        });

    //Ajax Done catch JSON from PHP 
        request.done(function(dataset){
            for (var index in dataset){ 
                 dataPHPtoJsJS=dataset[index].dataPHPtoJs;
                 asManyasYouWantJS=dataset[index].asYouWant;
             }

             //JavaScript conditions. Here you can control the behaivior of your html object, based on your PHP response
             if(dataPHPtoJsJS){
                $( "#idYourHtmlElement" ).removeClass( "class1" )
                $( "#idYourHtmlElement" ).addClass( "class2" )
             }


     }); 

    //Ajax Fail 
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        }); 
}
```

Note: Se for serializar use essa função:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

e se for enviar JSON a função toda ficaria assim:

```
var meuJson = JSON.stringfy($(form).serializeObject());
```